# In Python, Whenever I try to compare a string input to a variable that is a string, it will not work

Tags: python, random

I am new to Python and am currently trying to make Rock, Paper, Scissors to learn the language better. I, however, am having issues when asking the user for a choice. Here is the function that is acting up.

```py
def askUser():
    global userAnswerINTEGER
    global userAnswer
    global rock
    global paper
    global scissors
    userAnswer = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
    print(userAnswer)
    userAnswer = 0
    if userAnswer == (rock):
         userAnswerINTEGER = 1
         results()
    if userAnswer == (paper):
        userAnswerINTEGER = 2
        results()
    if userAnswer == (scissors):
        userAnswerINTEGER = 3
        results()
    if userAnswer != rock or paper or scissors:
        print('Please, pick a valid answer choice.')
        askUser()
```

I have additional variables within the file.

```py
rock = "Rock"
paper = "Paper"
scissors = "Scissors"
userAnswer = 0
```

However, no matter what I put in the prompt, it will always print 'Please, pick a valid answer choice.' How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code that together cause this issue.

The first issue is that you're not ending the current function call when you find a match, you just call some other function. When that function (eventually) returns, the function that called it will keep on running. Since all your `if` conditions are independent of each other, you'll test all the others after the function you called returns.

This is where the other issue comes in. Your condition for a bad value is written incorrectly. You have `if userAnswer != rock or paper or scissors:`, which I think you intend to mean "if userAnswer is not one of rock, paper, or scissors", but which Python interprets differently. Your condition is equivalent to `if (userAnswer != rock) or (paper) or (scissors)`. That is, the latter two variables are not being compared to `userAnswer`, but just being tested for "truthieness" directly. Python considers strings to be "falsey" only if they're empty, so both `"Paper"` and `"Scissors"` are true, so the condition is always met.

There are a variety of ways you can fix this issue. I'd suggest fixing *both* of the issues I identified above, by making all your conditions part of one larger compound statement using `if`, `elif` and `else`. This lets you get rid of the condition on the non-recognized input, since you'll have already ruled out all the valid inputs earlier in the statement:

```
if userAnswer == rock:
    ...
elif userAnswer == paper:
    ...
elif userAnswer == scissors:
    ...
else:
    print('Please, pick a valid answer choice.')
```

I'd also suggest that you use loops, rather than recursive function calls for your flow control. Put the whole block above (as well as the input prompt above it) into a `while True` loop and then make the successful match cases (the `if` and `elif` blocks) either `return` from the whole function, or `break` out of the loop (if you still have stuff to do that is common to all of them). Only the bad values will keep on looping, and they'll be able to do so indefinitely!

Answer (score 1):

What do you think `userAnswer = 0` does to the number you just typed?

A better way would be:

```
answers = { 'Rock': 1, 'Paper': 2, 'Scissors': 3 }
...
while 1:
  userAnswer = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
  if userAnswer in answers:
    break
  print( "Try again." )

userAnswerInteger = answers[userAnswer]
```

Comment: I don't see any way to exit the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enum.

```
import enum

class Game(enum.Enum):
    Rock=1
    Paper=2
    Scissors=3
    
    @staticmethod
    def play():
        userAnswer = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
        if userAnswer not in [e.name for e in Game]:
            print("Please, pick a valid answer choice.")
        else:
            for e in Game:
                if e.name == userAnswer:
                    print(e.value)
            
        Game.play()
```

> Game.play()